# Google data API for .Net allows Sharing outside organization in Google apps account

Tags: google-docs-api

I am using Google Data API for .Net(version 1.9) in my application. 
I have created a Google apps account and i have set the "Users cannot share documents outside this organization" setting under Google Docs.

When i try to share a file outside of the domain(organization) from Google docs web, i get a error saying the file cannot be shared outside of my domain.

But when i try the same thing from the API, it succeeds. I get a 200 success from the API. When i try to access the file from the share link it says 'You need permission to access this resource'. My question is shouldn't the API return with a error? how can i handle this case?

---

Here is the code that I am using:

```
DocumentsRequest request = null;   

/* request  initialization */

string csBatchReqBody = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gAcl="http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule"/><entry><id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document:1DsELtiNwq-ogOrp8cAONdMpGR4gBF79PjijTae-vVNg/acl/user:myusername@mydomain.com</id><batch:operation type="query"/></entry><entry><batch:id>1</batch:id><batch:operation type="insert"/><gAcl:role value="reader"/><gAcl:scope type="user" value="myusername@gmail.com"/></entry>"

string Url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document:1DsELtiNwq-ogOrp8cAONdMpGR4gBF79PjijTae-vVNg/acl/batch";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csBatchReqBody);
MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
AtomEntry reply = request.Service.Insert(new Uri(Url), inputStream, "application/atom+xml", "");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
reply.SaveToXml(stream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API actually returns a 400 if you try to share a file outside the domain and the admins have set the "Users cannot share documents outside this organization" flag.

Your code sends a batch request (even if for a single element), you'd have to check the batch response to notice the error.

Instead, use the following code to share a document to a single user, it assumes that `entry` is the `DocumentEntry` you want to share:

```
AclEntry acl = new AclEntry();
acl.Scope = new AclScope("username@gmail.com", "user");
acl.Role = new AclRole("reader");
acl = service.Insert(new Uri(entry.AccessControlList), acl);
```

Comment: thank you. So i should not be using batch requests for single element? just a clarification.

Comment: There's no need to use batch for a single request, it actually adds some overhead.